# ANDROID - How to find google account from "people api" and have and get a id

Tags: android, google-people-api

I'm creating an application with google identification.

I need to identify the google accounts of my friends from people API from "people/me"

Here my code:

```
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
            .build()
            .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

    People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .build();

    ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
```

The issue: I don't know how to identify the google accounts founded.
Explanation: i want find the google accounts and use a "id" to send a notification when this one is connected on my app.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You can do something similar to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771034/7187774

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.setRequestMaskIncludeField("person.names,person.emailAddresses,person.phoneNumbers")
                                   .execute();`

to response object. Because by default selection of filed for user profile is empty, so you should specify fields to select